# Toggle Event Listeners

Tags: javascript, function, scope, dom-events, event-listener

I am trying to make a function that would allow me to toggle eventListener of an element.

In the example below, I have three buttons: ***main***, ***on*** and ***off***. When I click on the ***on*** button, the ***main*** button becomes functional. After I click ***off*** button, the ***main*** button should not work anymore (but now it still does).

Now I can achieve a desired behavior by clicking ***on*** button for the second time, but I guess it's a bad coincidence and it's not supposed to work that way.

Maybe I should add that I would like to work this out without using jQuery or similar and it needs to be a function, because I am going to use it for a lot of buttons.

(I suspect something with scope causes the problem (*clickHandler* when calling the function to *activate* the button is not the same as the *clickHandler* when calling the function to *disable* the button), but I can't think of a way to test it.)

```js
// buttons definitions, not important
var mainButton = document.querySelector("#mainButton");
var onButton = document.querySelector("#onButton");
var offButton = document.querySelector("#offButton");

// main function
var toggleButtons = function(toggleVal, button, element) {
    var activateButton, clickHandler, disableButton;

    // callback function for listener bellow
    clickHandler = function() {
        document.querySelector(element).classList.toggle("yellow");
    };

    activateButton = function() {
        button.addEventListener("click", clickHandler);
    };
    disableButton = function() {
        button.removeEventListener("click", clickHandler);
    };

    // when first argument is 1, make the button functional, otherwise disable its functionality
    if (toggleVal === 1) {
        activateButton();
    } else {
        disableButton();
    }
};

// when onButton is clicked, call main function with arguments
// this works
onButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    toggleButtons(1, mainButton, "body");
});

// this fails to disable the button
offButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    toggleButtons(0, mainButton);
});
```

```css
.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="mainButton">mainButton
</button>
<button type="button" id="onButton">onButton
</button>
<button type="button" id="offButton">offButton
</button>
<p>mainButton: toggles background color on click
</p>
<p>onButton: turns on mainButtons's functionality</p>
<p>offButton: supposed to turn off mainButton's functionality</p>
```

Comment: You have a typo `offButon`.

Comment: (P.S. you could just use `true` and `false` for `toggleVal`.)

Comment: Thank you, the typo is (unfortunately) not the reason the code is not working :( True/false is of course an option, it just made semantical sense to me that 1 = on, and 0 = off.

Comment: I would not do this by constantly switching event handlers on and off ... rather just set a flag (maybe on the element itself, as a custom data attribute) that tells the one initial handler, _"should I react to this click event, or just let it pass by this time?"_

Comment: Wow, I am an idiot. That could really be a solution. I will let you know after I try.

Comment: @CBroe +1000000 to you! I spent days trying to figure this out only to find out that the solution is this simple <3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var mainButton = document.querySelector("#mainButton");
var onButton = document.querySelector("#onButton");
var offButon = document.querySelector("#offButton");

var element; // declare the element here and change it from toggleButtons when needed.

function clickHandler() {
    document.querySelector(element).classList.toggle('yellow');
}
function activateButton(button) { // You missed this part
    button.addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
}
function disableButton(button) { // You missed this part
    button.removeEventListener('click', clickHandler);
}

function toggleButtons(value, button) {    
    if (value === 1) {
        activateButton(button);  // You missed this part
    } else {
        disableButton(button);  // You missed this part
    }
};

onButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    element = 'body'; // you can change it to some other element 
    toggleButtons(1, mainButton);
});
offButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    element = 'body'; // you can change it to some other element 
    toggleButtons(0, mainButton);
});
```

Comment: Ok. I updated my answer, you weren't passing reference to the `mainButton` and that's why it didn't work.

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to provide arguments to clickHandler? Then it would be absolutely perfect!

Comment: I updated JS in question so it illustrates better what I am trying to achieve. In case I need to pass value from toggleButtons to clickHandler, with this I cannot ...

Comment: In your answer, 6th line:
`document.body.classList.toggle('red');`
What I mean is, that I would like to make `document.body` variable. So instead, I want something like this:
`document.querySelector(element)`, where `element` is always different.
The problem is that I don't know, how to pass a variable to named callback function (clickHandler).

Comment: You cannot pass it to the `clickHandler` but you can declare it somewhere outside and then use it. You can change `element` to some other element and it will be used from inside `clickHandler`.

Comment: I like your current solution, let me try it out.

Comment: Well, my code became really messy because of those outside variable declarations, but it's WORKING!!! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Below code helps to toggle between two functions from an eventListener:

```
   var playmusic=false;
    function playSound() {
      const audio = document.querySelector(`audio[data-key="${event.keyCode}"]`)
      audio.currentTime = 0
      audio.play()
      playmusic=true;
    }
    function stopSound() {
      const audio = document.querySelector(`audio[data-key="${event.keyCode}"]`)
      audio.pause()
      playmusic=false;
    }
    
    window.addEventListener('keydown',
    function(){playmusic?stopSound():playSound()} )
```